# Store a line as string and Output later in C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to store a line of printed statement as string and output the line later in other part ?

If no then is there other method ? Provided that the line printed is not entered by user but need to use it to display at other part.

Tried google but still no clue about it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and what I had tried so far is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int choice;
char line[20];    //variable to store the line 
printf("Enter your choice\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);
switch(choice){
case 1:
    printf("You had selected first choice\n");    //this line wanted to be store as string and output at bottom 
line[20]="You had selected first choice"; // error C2440
scanf("%s", &line); // probably I could use this to store the line ? 
break;

default:
    exit(0);
}
printf("%s", line); // display the line which has been store in above 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `char line[20]` for this (for many reasons). Use `const char *line`. Then you can `line = "You selected whatever you selected";` to make the assignment, and you can print it later if you wish.

Comment: 1) How do you want to store? Define "later". 2) Format&indent your code. As it is now, it is hard to read.

Comment: **Do not** access `line[20]`, which is out-of-range,

Comment: Increase size of `line` and then use `strcpy` to store string in it .

Comment: @mah: Bad advice without additional information for an obvious beginner. An array serves a different purpose than a pointer.

Comment: @olaf one can always add additional information to make a solution look good or bad. I'm just using the information as presented, which includes an example of its use - `printf("%s", line);`. If you feel there are corner cases which could get the implementation in trouble, perhaps leave a more substantial / helpful comment or, better yet, answer.

Comment: @mah Thanks for the feedback, I realize there were a few careless mistake I did. I'm a beginner in c code programming as I had just started in c programming 1 month ago and it is one of the subject I'm studying during this semester in my university. However, I understand more about it after MikeCAT shows the example. Appreciate for his correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do not access `line[20]`, which is out-of-range.
- 20-byte array is too small to store `"You had selected first choice"`, which is 29-character and 30-byte (incluting terminating null character) long.
- `scanf("%s", &line);` is undefined behavior because of type mismatch: `"%s"` expect `char*` and `&line` is `char(*)[20]`.

You can use `strcpy()` to copy null-terminated strings.

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> // for using exit()
#include<string.h> // for using strcpy()
int main(void)
{
    int choice;
    char line[64];    //variable to store the line 
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        printf("%s\n", strcpy(line, "You had selected first choice"));
        break;

    default:
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("%s", line); // display the line which has been store in above 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems, the first is that `line[X]` is a *single character* and you try to assign a string to it (`line[20]` is out of bounds by the way). The second problem is that you can't assign to an array, you can initialize an array at definition, or you can *copy* to it, using e.g. [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). The third error is that the string you try to copy to the array is *much* longer than 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
// In general do a formatted output to char array,  
// and use it as you like.  
sprintf(line, "%s", "You had selected first choice\n");  
printf("%s", line);
```